# Function to get variable name data type and value

Tags: python, printing

I have a variable a=2, b (an array), etc.

I'm finding a function like the magic command %whos that print all existing variables. But i want to applied the same function of %whos but for just one variable.

%whos returns all variables info, example

### Variable         Type             Data/Info

label            str              7
line             str              train\7\567_2.mat 7
local_vars       list             n=36

I want a function supponse named 'info', and i input variable 'label', then i want that info(label) print the related info: 'variable: label, Type: str, Data/info: 7'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def info(variable):
    my_variable = globals()[variable]
    return {"variable": variable, "type": type(my_variable), "data": my_variable}
```

Comment: Thanks. But give me an error. If my input is a list i have this error: "unhashable type: 'list'". If is a string or a int, also gives me an KeyError.

Comment: Variable should be string, ever